# How to center a placeholder in a textarea without the text cursor starting in the middle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example I have

```
<textarea placeholder="blah blah blah">

</textarea>
```

and I try to center the placeholder like so...

```
textarea[placeholder]
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

but when I do that, the textbox cursor starts in the middle instead of the left.

So how do I get the placeholder message to show up in the center of the textarea without changing the starting cursor area?

Comment: Can you provide some reference to the `previewtarget` attribute? I'm not aware of it and can't find it on web.

Comment: Oh sorry sorry brain fart, that was supposed to be "placeholder" not previewtarget, previewtarget is an ID for something I've been messing with far too much today.

Comment: Now it makes sense. :) BTW with `textarea[placeholder]` selector you are applying style to `textarea` that has `placeholder` attribute, not on the `placeholder` itself.

Comment: Ohhh I see that's what that does...my mistake. That's very useful information though, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to [style the `placeholder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610741/451969) with a special syntax for [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) that is vendor-specific:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmhu4a3x/2/

Comment: Thanks alot! I don't really understand how that works but thanks! (also sorry about posting a what was probably a duplicate, if I had remembered what it was called properly I wouldn't have had to ask)

Comment: ```::placeholder``` is all that you need for modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder